# Vector subscription error

Tags: c++, image, filtering, subscription

I am writing some image filtering code in C++ but while creating the code I am getting an error like "vector subscription out of range". I traced the locals and couldn't figure what the problem is. The only thing that I know is there's a problem with  my filtering operation. Here's my code:

```
int filtersize;

cout << "enter the filter size" ;
cin >> filtersize ;

int a = (filtersize-1)/2, i=a, j=a;

vector <vector<int>> filter (filtersize, vector <int>(filtersize, 0));
vector <vector<int>> filtered (countRow, vector <int>(countCol, 0));

int avg=0;
int average=0;

for(int x=0; x< mat.size(); x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y< mat[0].size(); y++)
    {
        for (int m=-a; m<=a; m++)
        {
            for(int n=-a; n<=a; n++)
            {
                if(y + n >= 0 &&
                   x + m >= 0 &&
                   y + n <= mat[0].size() &&
                   x + m <= mat.size())
                {
                    avg = avg + mat[x+m] [y+n];
                }
            }
        }

        average = avg / (filtersize * filtersize);
        filtered[x][y] = average;
        avg = 0;

        Print(filtered);
    }
}
```

The `mat` matrix is the input matrix for the program.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should check `x+m < mat.size()` first *then* check `y+n < mat[x+m].size()`

```
if (y+n>=0 && x+m>=0 && x+m < mat.size() &&  y+n < mat[x+m].size())
```

notes: check `<` and not `<=` and check against `mat[x+m]` and not mat[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing your mat at its size, which is not legal. You must be in range `[0, size)`.

Try this : `y+n < mat[0].size()  &&  x+m < mat.size()`